# Get Primary Key Column of a Table

Tags: sql-server

I want to be sure that this is the right way of getting the pk name, schema, table name and column name for a given table Name

```
SELECT i.name AS IndexName,
       (SELECT SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]) FROM sys.[tables] WHERE [object_id] = ic.OBJECT_ID) SchemaName,
       OBJECT_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
       COL_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID,ic.column_id) AS ColumnName
  FROM sys.indexes AS i
 INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
    ON i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID
   AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
 WHERE i.is_primary_key = 1
   AND OBJECT_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID) = 'MyTable'
```

I believe this is working

```
SELECT i.name AS IndexName,
       SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]) SchemaName,
       OBJECT_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
       COL_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID,ic.column_id) AS ColumnName, 
       ic.key_ordinal
  FROM sys.indexes AS i
 INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
    ON i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID
   AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
 INNER JOIN sys.[tables] st
    ON st.[object_id] = ic.OBJECT_ID
 WHERE i.is_primary_key = 1
   AND SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]) = 'auth'
   AND OBJECT_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID) = 'Profile'
```

Comment: seems ok to me, why ask? are you having any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, no one "right way". This one works, but some fringe cases will slip you up. Some minor tweaks:

```
SELECT
  schema_name(t.schema_id) AS SchemaName
 ,t.name AS TableName
 ,i.name AS IndexName
 ,co.name AS ColumnName
 ,ic.key_ordinal AS ColumnOrder  --  [2]
  FROM sys.tables AS t
 INNER JOIN  sys.indexes AS i
    ON i.OBJECT_ID = t.OBJECT_ID
 INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
    ON i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID
   AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
 INNER JOIN sys.columns AS co
    ON co.column_id = ic.index_column_id
   AND co.object_id = t.object_id
 WHERE i.is_primary_key = 1
   AND t.name = 'MyTable'
   AND schema_name(t.schema_id) = 'dbo'  --  [1]
 ORDER BY ic.key_ordinal  --  [2]
```

[1] Lets you specify which schema you're searching (only matters if you have more than dbo defined)

[2] Covers compound (multi-column) indexes, and shows their order

Comment: You are right, I've got your point, but this query actually doesn't gives me the multi-columns PK if that's the purpose.

Comment: It returns one row per column in the index, not one column per column.